# Moodle get categories

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to create a theme that on the homepage it will display the categories and courses, I was able to get the courses with **get_courses()** function like that:

```
<?php $courses = get_courses(); ?>

<?php foreach ($courses as $key => $value) { ?>    
    <a href="course/view.php?id=<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <h2 class="title"><?php echo $courses[$key]->fullname; ?></h2>            
    </a>
    <p class="summary"><?php echo $courses[$key]->summary; ?></p> 
    <p class="category"><?php echo $courses[$key]->category; ?></p>       
<?php } ?>
```

Now I'm trying to get the categories,
the only thing I was able to get is the category ID with [$key]->category

How Can I get the category name and display it?

Comment: FYI, the idea of doing `foreach ($courses as $key => $value)` is so you can refer to `$value` in your loop instead of `$courses[$key]`.

Comment: haha, good to know, any idea of how to get categories maybe?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=205451), you should be able to get this info directly from the database:

```
<?php
$courses = get_courses();
foreach ($courses as $id=>$course) {
    $category = $DB->get_record('course_categories',array('id'=>$course->category));
    $course->categoryName = $category->name;
    $allcourses[$id] = $course;
}
?>
```

And then, in your display code:

```
<?php foreach($allcourses as $id=>$course):?>
    <a href="course/view.php?id=<?=$id?>">
        <h2 class="title"><?=$course->fullname?></h2>            
    </a>
    <p class="summary"><?=$course->summary?></p> 
    <p class="category"><?=$course->categoryName?></p>       
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: are you sure? I get nothing, what is categoryName? I did var_dump of $courses and I don't see any categoryName

Comment: Why would you? The whole point of the answer is that you're adding it.

Comment: Why would I what? It's not working.. if it was I wouldn't ask you

Comment: Why would you see `categoryName` in `$courses`, which is the output from `get_courses()`? You're adding it to `$allcourses`, which is then looped through for the display. And if it's not in there, I would check that `$DB` is accessible, and that the call to `$DB->get_record()` is returning data.

Comment: Fantastic, code works just as it is! THANKS. We have to check every single course to see if the user is enrolled, and redirect them in certain conditions.